# How to record application having both internet and intranet requests on same pages (e.g, Home page after Login) in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working with application which works mainly in intranet. Thus for recording i do not need to open my Jmeter behind proxy. But same application have few request for which I need internet. If i open my Jmeter behind proxy then request from intranet gets failed. How can I set up my Jmeter for recording so that it will record both intranet and internet request in same script.

Comment: what does it mean to "open my Jmeter behind proxy"? can you explain that in technical terms (i.e. what are you actually doing)? Also you may want to skip internet requests for your performance testing, if those communicate with 3rd-party sites, which did not authorize you to put load on their servers.

Comment: Behind proxy means i open my jmeter using command jmeter.bat -H (proxy server) -P (portNo) - u username -a password. Actually i need those request from internet to load  webpage completely during recording. If my webpage do not load completely i cant record the flow like, login-->home-->transaction-->logout

Comment: @UBIK LOAD PACK I tried the solution jmeter.bat -H (proxy server) -P (portNo) - u username -a password -N (non proxy host) ..bt it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In jmeter proxy setup you can exclude urls:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Look at option :

> -N